# Migrating Python 2 to Python 3

Tags: python-2.7, migration

Our firm descided to move all our automation and devops scripts from Python 2 to Python 3, what would be some of the best practices for such an undertaking?

Answer (score 1):

Try using future:

http://python-future.org/index.html

It allows you to use a single, clean Python 3.x-compatible codebase to support both Python 2 and Python 3 with minimal overhead.